# How quit a loop when my condition is met?

Tags: blueprism

I'm working with BluePrism and I have to loop though collections, sometimes there is +1000 rows.

**For example :**

I loop though a collection and search for the word "*hello*", if this word is found at row 10 I want to stop looping the rest 990 rows. And right after that do another loop for another word in the same collection and so on.

Is this possible ? Currently I'm looping til the end of the collection, It works fine but takes a lot of time.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

I don't have enough reputation to post image so there is the link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrp5p.jpg

Comment: You do not need reputation points to post code snippets. You need to provide the code you are trying to run. Preferably a snippet that can be executed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. There is no really a code in BluePrism, only if you use code stage and I'm not using that there. The snippets is the image link I posted.

Comment: I'm not going to click your image link. You need to follow the question guidelines.

Comment: I'm saying you that there is no code snippet in BluePrism. If you don't know what is it (BluePrism) and how it works, why are you commenting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not be using loops to find information in collections. For that there is an action called `Filter Collection` within the `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO.

Other than that, your code snippet is OK, that's how you would exit a loop based on a condition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do with the `Filter Collection` action